# Angular2 Observables -- Replay

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to set up an Angular2 Observable that will replay the latest value.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class RefinementService {
    refining: any;
    private r: any;
    constructor() {
        this.refining = new Observable(observer => this.r = observer).replay(1);
    }
}
```

I continually get errors stating:

> Property 'replay' does not exist on type Observable<{}>.

and

> this.refining.replay is not a function

Has anyone successfully implemented an observable that will re-emit it's latest value to new subscribers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [MIGRATION](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed) guide for [RxJS5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) `replay` was renamed to `publishReplay`.

So you should be fine by adding the correct operator

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishReplay';

// Component
this.refining = new Observable(observer => this.r = observer).publishReplay(1);
```

You could use [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could try to refact your code this way:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable,ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RefinementService {
  refining: any;
  private r: any;
  constructor() {
    this.refining = new Observable(observer => this.r = observer)
        .subscribe(new ReplaySubject(1));
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TrCf8JEGO1toEMqiWg3D?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry