# Angular2 multiple components using one REST call

Tags: rest, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am part of a Angular2 application (we use beta3) and the issue is the following:

Usually we have a component that uses some service that uses some rest call and the component displays the data. Great.

However we do have a page with more then 6 components all of them using the same REST call...(the backend returns data for ALL of them) and it doesn't make sense to call 6 times the REST for each component, also it will be weird if we do some client side caching.

Is there something available out of the box ? Or a Pattern to handle such case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it in a shared service. If you add it only in `bootstrap(..., [OtherProviders, HTTP_PROVIDERS, MyService])` each component will get injected the same instance. Store the data in the service and every component can access it

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private dataService:MyService) {
    dataService.getData().subscribe(data => { this.data = data; });
  }
}
```

```ts
export class MyService {
  getData() {
    if(!this.data) {
      return http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(data => { this.data = data;});
    } 
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The @Günter's answer really makes sense!

I don't know your code is organized but observable can also be subscribed several times. To do that you need to make them "hot" using the `share` operator:

```
export class MyService {
  dataObservable:Observable;

  initDataObservable() {
    this.dataObservable = http.get(...).map(...).share();
  } 
}
```

Without using the `share` operator, corresponding request will executed several times (one per subscribe).

You can notice that the request will be executed once one `subscribe` method is called on the observable.

Comment: Interesting. How I understand it, only events that arrive **after** subscribing will be sent to the subscriber. If the request initiated by the first subscriber already arrived when the next subscribers subscribe, they'll just wait for events never to arrive. I think this `share` makes only sense for events like "mousemove" where you don't care what happened before you subscribe. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, agreed! Only the subscribers registered when the event occurs will be notified using the `share` operator. That said, I know that there is a `publishReplay` operator that allows you to receive the event even if you subscribe later. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947642/angular2-observables-replay. Honestly I never use it ;-) I guess that you could call it when subscribing...

Comment: `EventEmitter` follows this since it's an hot observable (through `Subject`)... I mean the mechanism you described in your comment.